Can the formula for magnetic field intensity be used for cores with varying cross sectional area?
Can the formula H = NI/l be used for cores with varying cross sectional areas?

You could approximate it with the average crosssectional area, if you need a more exact answer you'll need to use the integral and a function of cross sectional area


Can the formula H = NI/l be used for cores with varying cross
sectional areas?

The above formula can be used anywhere that is applicable in magnetics. The formula doesn't care about the core cross section or the material permeability because H is equivalent to voltage i.e. the voltage apply in an electric circuit.
Electric current is equivalent to magnetic flux density. As we know, electric current is defined by the voltage divided by the resistance and, resistance has the equivalence of magnetic reluctance.
Both electric and magnetic relationships are generally regarded as a type of ohm's law.
H only cares about the magneto motive force (ampere turns) and the length (\$\ell\$) of the path that a field line travels.
Flux density on the other hand totally relies on H, permeability and cross sectional area but, that wasn't your question.
